# Validating a console input

Tags: c#, validation

My mind has gone completely blank as to how to validate a null text value

All I need to do is check if an entered value is blank, if so ask again without continuing.

```
Console.WriteLine("Venue Name - ");
String venName = Console.ReadLine();
```

I can think how to do it with various loops and IF statements, but I'm sure there's a far more efficient way, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how or why you would do it without a loop or an if statement.  Try this:

```
String venName = null;
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(venName)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Venue Name - ");
    venName = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's exactly what I was after, I was trying to get it like that but was clearly going about it the wrong way. Again- Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(venName)` to check the user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(venName))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` to check and see if the input is null, blank, or consists of all whitespace characters.  Depending on your use-case this may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post, and I'm pretty new to c#, but here's another way to do it with a method call, which could be used for any such validation instead of writing redundant code:

```
string venName = null;
WriteName(venName);

public static void WriteName(string name)
{
    while(String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Venue name - ");
         name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```